# Unable to play a 3gp video in android

Tags: android

Firstly, I am able to display a 3gp video from server in android. But in my project all are .flv videos. So using a video converter I converted the flv videos to 3gp
and then I tried to play those converted 3gp videos. But this time it is displaying this video cannot be played. What could be the reason and how to solve this issue. Please help me in this regard.

```
package com.play.video;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayvideofromserverActivity extends Activity
{
    private VideoView vView;
    private String vSource;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        vView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);


        vView.requestFocus();


            vSource ="http://server.com/video.3gp";
            vView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vSource));


        vView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));


        vView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ user1448108 3gp files are commonly not supported in android application.Android application certainly plays particular formats like mp3,flv,,Are u working on a demo app or android project.Plz specify clearly Plz let me know,,,,,if you are still facing an issue. Regards
Tushar

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your 3GP files are correct? When converting, there is always a possibility something went wrong or the converter doesn't convert the files right. I suggest you retrieve an original 3GP to test it in stead of an converted one.